# как сделать так, чтобы окно открывалось только на главной странице портала, работает на liferay 7

Tags: javascript, popup

```js
var delay_popup = 1000;

 setTimeout("document.getElementById('wrap').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
```

```css
 #wrap{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.725);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 
 #popup{
  width: 421px;
  height: 168px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
 }
 
 .close{
  margin-left: 407px;
  margin-top: -44px;
  cursor: auto;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Задний прозрачный фон-->
  <div  id="wrap">

     <!-- окно-->
   <div id="popup">
      
       <!-- Картинка крестика-->
    <img class="close" style="position:relative" onclick="document.getElementById('wrap').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';" src="/home/banner/close.png">
     
      <!-- Картинка -->
    <p><a href="https://бизнес-признание.рф"><img  style="margin-top:-32px; margin-left:-16px;" src="/home/banner.png"></a></p>
    
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` - узнаем на какой страницы находится человек и сравниваем адресом главной страницы. Как вариант сравнить с `location.hostname` - доменное имя

```
if (window.location == 'адрес сайта'){
твой код открытия окна
}
```

или так

```
if (window.location == location.hostname){
твой код открытия окна
}
```

Должно работать. Ну смысл понятен.

Answer (score 0):

Передавай параметр окна в BackingBean и вызывай оттуда при загрузке главной страницы. Не думаю что привязываться к ссылке хорошая идея, потому что ссылка одна на портлет.
В Liferay каждому портлету, и скорее всего странице присваивается id, можешь попробовать привязаться к нему.